# React & Typescript passing HTML types into custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How would I pass the type annotation using the `as SVGElement` or `as HTMLDivElement` etc...
into a hook

```js
function AppSVG(){
    const ref = useResizeObserver((entry) => {
        ...
    }) as SVGElement;// <- how do I pass SVGElement to the hook

    return <svg ref={ref} />
}

function AppDiv(){
    const ref = useResizeObserver((entry) => {
        ...
    }) as HTMLDivElement;// <- how do I pass HTMLDivElement to the hook

    return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

The hook

```js
function useResizeObserver(observerCallback: ResizeObserverCallback) {
    const ref = React.useRef<any>(null);//<- into the ref

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!!ref && !!ref.current)
            new ResizeObserver(observerCallback).observe(ref.current);
    }, []);

    return ref;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

more or less this is what I was going for Bastiat's answer was nearly complete.  I had to include `<T extends Element>`.

hook:

```js
function useResizeObserver<T extends Element>(observerCallback: (element: T, entry: ResizeObserverEntry[]) => void, options?: ResizeObserverOptions) {
    const ref = React.useRef<T>(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!!ref && !!ref.current) {
            const element = ref.current;
            new ResizeObserver((entry) => observerCallback(element, entry)).observe(element, options);
        }
    }, []);

    return ref;
}
```

component:

```js
    const ref = useResizeObserver<HTMLDivElement>((element) => {
        const height = element.offsetWidth;
        const width = element.offsetHeight;
        setState({ width, height });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) you can pass your type in as a sort of argument. useRef takes a generic itself, so you can create your own generic type and pass it into useRef.

```
function useResizeObserver<T>(observerCallback: ResizeObserverCallback) {
    const ref = React.useRef<T>(null);//<- into the ref
    ...
}
```

use:

```
const ref = useResizeObserver<HTMLDivElement>();
```